# Get two aside sections to float left with fixed width CSS

Tags: css, css-float

I'm trying for two sections to float aside of the main column on the right side. The sections should be of a fixed width and the main should be fluid. This is the closest I have come. Problem is that the main does not change its size. If it where one aside section I had used the holy grail, but that doesn't work either.

[edit]To clarify; the HTML cannot be changed (much). Left and right need to stay after main which is best for screen readers and seo. The asides are actually the left and right column if content is wide enough. So only specific widths get this layout I am trying to achieve.[/edit]

https://jsfiddle.net/TR2SD/1/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="main">
        main contents<br>with some content
    </div>
    <aside id="left">
        left contents
    </aside>
    <aside id="right">
        right contents
    </aside>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
}

#main {
    border: 1px dotted #f0f;
    margin: 0 -240px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

#left {
    background-color: #0ff;
}

#right {
    background-color: #ff0;
}

#left,#right {
    float: left;
    width:220px;
    position: relative;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally answered it by utilizing an inside element of the #main. What I need to check is compatibility of this fix. And what haapens to the backgrounds assigned to #main.

https://jsfiddle.net/TR2SD/5/

I added an "inside" element

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="main">
        <div class="inside">
        main contents<br>with some content
        </div>
    </div>
    <aside id="left">
        left contents
    </aside>
    <aside id="right">
        right contents
    </aside>
</div>
```

And the css floats everything with some corrections.

```
#container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
}

#main {
    background-color: #f0f;
    margin-left: -240px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

#main .inside {
    margin-left: 240px;
}

#left {
     background-color: #0ff;
}

#right {
     background-color: #ff0;
}

#left,#right {
    float: left;
    width:240px;
}
```

Comment: I did need to add a js later on to always make the main the min-height of left + 10px so right would not float on the left. But it was a minor issue as the css solves all other problems.

Answer (score 1):

In order to locate your divs as you are requiring you should:

Position  divs left and right  floating right

For the div you named **left** to be placed  to the left of **right** , you must declare **right** before left and lastly **main** which does not require to be positioned relative
The **container** should declare a min width to prevent the break of the lay out.

**So HTML should be a sort of...**

```
<div id="container">
     <aside id="right">
        right contents
    </aside>
    <aside id="left">
        left contents
    </aside>   
    <div id="main">
        main contents<br>with some content
    </div>
</div>
```

**And CSS should be**

```
#container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
     min-width:600px;
}

#main {
    border: 1px dotted #f0f;
    margin: 0 -240px 0 0;    
}

#left {
     background-color: #0ff;
}

#right {
     background-color: #ff0;
}

#left,#right {
    float: right;
    width:220px;        
}
```

From here onwards, adjust as your will
A [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Fico/G28Mn/)

Comment: Note the sidebar will disappear if the page is shrunk.

Comment: Note the sidebar will disappear if the page is shrunk past the specified `min-width`. You should use a media query to adjust as described in my answer to create a better user experience.

Comment: Actually, this answer is incorrect. I need an answer for the given HTML. HTML cannot be re-ordered, that would make the answer easy. SEO, screen readers and other reasons.

Comment: Sorry Fico, forgot to thank you for the effort. But placing the content in a specific order to get the desired result is the easy way out. I'm sure there must be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

For one sidebar, you can position in by accounting for its width using padding on the container and a margin on the main section:

```
.container {
    padding-right: 200px; /* Matches sidebar width */
    overflow: hidden;
}

.main {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 200px; 
    margin-right: -200px; /* Matches sidebar width */
    float: right;
}
```

For a left and right sidebar with a scaling center you can use a similar technique:

```
.container {
    padding-right: 200px;
    padding-left: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.main {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.left-sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: -200px;
}

.right-sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: -200px;
}

.left-sidebar, .right-sidebar {
    display: none;
}
```

Here's the [final result on JSBin](https://jsbin.com/ujaxuh/13/edit). You'll need to resize the page to see the different views.

Note that an auxiliary sidebar for small screens was used in the example above as it is inordinately difficult to use CSS to render elements out of DOM order.

Comment: I think I need to elaborate (and add that to the question). The left and right asides are normally the left and right sidebar. But to conserve space I need them both on the right for specific sizes. I'm not sure, but don't think your answer can handle that?

Comment: I added a two column example as well. Forcing the elements out of DOM order deserves another question. It's a far more tricky bit to accomplish. If you're concerned about screen readers, you could mask the auxiliary sidebar with the appropriate aria attributes.